# Testing two mean effect sizes in meta-analysis for significant differences

Tags: effect, mean

I run two meta-analysis and want to proof that the caluclated mean effect size (in fisher z) differs between both meta-analysis.

As i am quit new in R and not such a pro in statistics, could you provide the appropriate test and how to conduct it in R?

Here are my current results of the two meta analysis:

```
> results1GN

Random-Effects Model (k = 4; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0921 (SE = 0.0752)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.3034
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   99.98%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  5569.05

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 3) = 22183.0526, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
  0.3663   0.1517   2.4139   0.0158   0.0689   0.6637        * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

> results1NN

Random-Effects Model (k = 72; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0521 (SE = 0.0096)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.2282
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   95.98%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  24.85

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 71) = 1418.1237, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
  0.2594   0.0282   9.2016   <.0001   0.2042   0.3147      ***
```

Comment: A description/illustration of how this can be done can be found on the metafor package website (which the user apparently used for the analyses) at: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates

Answer (score -1):

I elaborate on the previous response, which was a bit rude.

On first step, you may consider the confidence interval of you result.
You may consult the Wikipedia page on the topic for a quick summary:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Anyway, in your example you have two effect sizes with overlapping confidence interval:

results1GN = 0.36 (95%CI: 0.069 to 0.66)

results1NN = 0.26 (95%CI:  0.20 to 0.31).

So, the two results are not statistically different.

The package 'metafor' also includes a function (anova) to compare "nested models", and I quote: 
"For two (nested) models of class "rma.uni", the function provides a full versus reduced model comparison in terms of model fit statistics and a likelihood ratio test".

Note that "When specifying two models for comparison, the function provides a likelihood ratio test comparing the two models. The models must be based on the same set of data and should be nested for the likelihood ratio test to make sense".

You may found more details and examples on the use of the function here: 
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/metafor/docs/anova.rma.uni

Also, consult the manual of the package and the the site of the package maintainer.

Hope this may be helpful.